# How do I move tokens (OMG) from a contract wallet address to another wallet address?

Tags: wallets

Hello I know how to send my tokens from my normal wallet address using MyEtherWallet but I cannot figure out how to send tokens that I have on a contract address (in the same wallet) to another wallet address.

The tokens are OMG which I recently received from Omise.

I can see the tokens listed on my contract (on etherscan.io) but have no idea how to move them.

Can anyone give me step by step instructions? Thanks.

Comment: I should have mentioned - I have successfully moved Ethereum Classic units from that contract a few weeks ago, although I understand that this fact still doesn't mean I will be able to move other tokens.

Comment: Did you sort this out? having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If a contract wasn't designed to allow it to move tokens that it owns, then those tokens will be unrecoverable.

Some contracts are designed to be "upgradable" or proxy contracts which allow you to run new or arbitrary code, but most aren't. That's usually a good thing, because it means you can have strong guarantees about what a contract is allowed to do.

Comment: It was just a standard contract which I used to send Ethereum into back in the day. I set it up on Ethereum Wallet on my desktop. At that time I didn't even know you couldn't have multiple addresses in an Ethereum wallet (unlike Bitcoin) - I didn't intend to set up a new address, I just wanted to transfer ETH into my wallet and didn't want to use the original address for privacy reasons, so the contract got created. It seems ridiculous that those OMG will sit there forever when I an the only owner of the contract and why didn't OMISE take this into account when they were doing their airdrop?

Comment: Can't the contract be transferred to another wallet/account and the tokens moved that way?

Comment: A contract isn't owned by an account, unless it has code that simulates ownership by that account. Without seeing the contract you have, I'd just be guessing.

Comment: This is the first significant airdrop I know of, hopefully the next one will work out some kinks. It is not trivial to prevent this issue.

Comment: Would you like to see the contract?

Comment: Here is is:

https://etherscan.io/address/0xE8395e86b953835354Cf4bC8eb90a704361AA7B0

Comment: This line is pretty promising `_to.call.value(_value)(_data)`. I can't make any promises, but it's more likely than I expected that you could get the OMG out.

Comment: Hi Carver, thanks, but I don't know how to ACTUALLY do that (I'm not a coder).

Any chance you could run me through it? Thanks, Adam.

Comment: A runthrough of that is complicated enough that it's probably too broad for a single StackExchange answer. You could try reddit.com/r/ethdev. If no luck there, you could hire someone to do it for you on something like ethlance.